# iOS 7 - Create fixed footer with buttons

Tags: ios, ios7, storyboard

I have a ViewController that has a ScrollView that will display a article. 
The user can rate it with a like or dislike.

I need to put a fixed footer Label that will display these buttons.
That label will be displayed above the ScrollView, just like the NavigationBar.

Right now I am not able to put a button inside the label and when I put the label I cannot scroll anymore.

Any one knows how to do this?

Comment: What what what? Button inside a label? what?

Comment: I am sorry. I am new with Objective-C and I thought that the Label was like the equivalent to a LinearLayout in Android. I already find a solution and decreases the size of my ScrollView

Comment: Use UIView. I think that's what you're looking for.